# How do you do MySQL trigger with select that includes sums and counts?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a db table with 30 million rows and obviously even with indexes created have issues with query times when doing even simple counts, sums and averages.

I believe that using a trigger would be solve for this problem but wanted to ask the community.

Here is what I am working but having trouble with:

```
 delimiter //
        create trigger after_products_update
        after inserton product_stats
        for each row begin
        select distinct product_cat, count(distinct product), sum(revenue), avg(cost) from products_table; 
        END; //
        delimiter ;
```

I guess a good closing would be ...am I on the right route here?

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Comment: It appears you want to have a summary table. Trigger like the one you have could make things worse. If query times are bad right now, triggering the same bad query on every insert will cause more problems - if I am understanding your question correctly

Comment: If you are using `sum()` and `avg()` the entire table needs to be read. Indexes won't help unless they contain all the columns named in your query (because then the rest of the columns won't need to be read). But for a very large table this will incur it's own costs. Perhaps you should post the slow query and ask for assistance with tuning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that using a trigger would be solve for this problem

NO, it's not. In essence what you are trying to do is; after every insert running a `SELECT` query on 30M rows which shouldn't be done. Generally, triggers are for doing some DML operation on some other table based on DML operation in your table.

You should run your `SELECT` query once all the `INSERT` statements are performed for verification.

Comment: Well this the answer I was looking for...like I mentioned I wasn't sure. Gotta love the 'NO' in all caps by the way...